# Android Grdidview of buttons

Tags: android, gridview

I want gridview with buttons. following is the code of main page.

```
    GridView gridview1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);    
    gridview1.setAdapter(new Buttonadapter(this));
    gridview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {       
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long id)
                       {  

                TextView temp=(TextView)arg1;  
                CharSequence  temp2=temp.getText(); 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), Diseasemain.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("disease", temp2);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
    });
```

here is the code of buttonadapter class

```
public class Buttonadapter  extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;   
public Buttonadapter(Context c) 
{        mContext = c;    }    
public int getCount() 
{        return mThumbIds.length;    }   
public Object getItem(int position) 
{        return null;    }    
public long getItemId(int position)
{        return 0;    }    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter    
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{        Button btn;        
        if (convertView == null) 
        {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes          
            btn = new Button(mContext); 
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    // Perform action on click 
                 } 
             }); 

    btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParam(85,85));           
            btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);       
            } 
        else 
        {           
            btn = (Button) convertView;       
            }       
        btn.setText(mThumbIds[position]);      
        return btn;    }  

private String[] mThumbIds =
    {           
        "hi",
        "bye",
        "heelo"
        }
;}
```

the problem is whenever I click on any button its not firing the onclick event nd not starting the next page also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the empty onclick method in your adapter is stopping
the itemclick listener from firing.
Try putting the code that starts the next page in the onclick instead.